# Getting core :: Program aborted with core

Tags: c++, coredump

I have used two classes: one Dataprocessor which will be processing file and count the total number of instances of that word in every line.
Tried to do it with multi-threading where thread will be initiated to take care of search in each line.

Storing count from each line in vector.

When executing without multi-threading, it's doing fine.

```
    void DataProcessor::countInstance ()
    {
            int pos = -1, count = 0;
            string lineFromFile;
            cout << "In countInstance" <<endl;
            getline (m_file, lineFromFile);        <<<< Not getting line read from file
            while(true)
            {
                    pos = lineFromFile.find(mStr_word, ++pos);
                    if (pos != std::string::npos)
                            count++;
                    else
                            break;
            }
            mVec_countPerLine.push_back(count);
            cout <<mStr_word << "****" <<lineFromFile <<endl;
            cout << mVec_countPerLine[0]<<endl;
    }
    DataProcessor::~DataProcessor()
    {
            m_file.close();
    }

    ////////

    void *ThreadFunction (void *dp)
    {
            pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex1 );
            DataProcessor *dProcessor = static_cast<DataProcessor *> (dp); <<<just curious if casting is creating a problem

            cout << "IN ThreadFunction"<< endl;
            dProcessor->countInstance ();
            pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex1 );
    }

    class MyThread
    {
    private:
            pthread_t threads[10];
    public:
            MyThread ();
            void createThread (DataProcessor *);
            ~MyThread ();
    };
```

Here I am creating threads in a loop

```
    void MyThread::createThread (DataProcessor *dProcessor)
    {
            cout << "IN CREATE THREAD::";
            int numLinesInFile, rc;
            numLinesInFile = dProcessor->getNumLinesInFile();
            for ( int i =0; i < numLinesInFile; i++)
            {
                    rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL,
                                            ThreadFunction, (void *)&dProcessor);
                    if (rc)
                    {
                            cout << "Error:unable to create thread," << rc << endl;
                            exit(-1);
                    }
            }
            for ( int i =0; i < numLinesInFile; i++)
                    pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
            pthread_exit(NULL);
    }

    MyThread::~MyThread ()
    {
    }


    ########################################################
    Calling these two objects from:-

            dProcessor.openFile("example.txt");
            dProcessor.setWord(readData);
            MyThread thread;
            thread.createThread (&dProcessor);
            dProcessor.displayResult();
```

But getting:

```
    IN CREATE THREAD::IN ThreadFunction
    In countInstance
    terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_cast'
      what():  std::bad_cast
    Aborted (core dumped)
```

Can anyone help me figure out the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

Your cast says that the parameter is a pointer to `DataProcessor`:

```
 static_cast<DataProcessor *> (dp);
```

but you're passing a pointer to a pointer to `DataProcessor`:

```
(void *)&dProcessor
```

Lose the cast and the ampersand:

```
rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, ThreadFunction, dProcessor);
```

By the way: you never need to cast a pointer into a `void*`.